# Fuzzy match of strings using python

Tags: python-3.4, distance

I have a record set as below.

```
"product_id"|"prod_descr"|"status"|"last_upd_time"
"102317"|"TELMINORM CH 40/12.5MG TAB 10'S"|"A"|"2016-08-31 15:02:06.609879"
"99996"|"BECOSTAR TAB 15'S"|"A"|"2016-09-05 18:20:25"
"99997"|"SUPRADYN TABLET15S"|"A"|"2016-09-06 09:05:24"
"120138"|"LASILACTONE 50MG TABLET 10'S"|"A"|"2016-09-07 12:01:05"
"101921"|"TELMA 20MG TABLET 15S"|"A"|"2016-08-31 15:02:06.609879"
"1220"|"ACNESTAR SOAP 75GM"|"A"|"2016-08-31 15:02:06.609879"
"120147"|"AMANTREL CAPSULES 15S"|"A"|"2016-09-09 09:54:35"
"113446"|"VOLIX 0 3MG TABLET 15S"|"A"|"2016-08-31 15:02:06.609879"
"121294"|"maxifer xt syrup "|"A"|"2016-09-29 15:32:40"
"120151"|"PIRITON CS SYRUP 100ML"|"A"|"2016-09-09 14:30:46"
"103481"|"TERBICIP SPRAY 30ML"|"A"|"2016-08-31 15:02:06.609879"
"96175"|"SORBITRATE 5MG TABLET 50S"|"A"|"2016-08-31 15:02:06.609879"
```

The set is as huge as a million records. I want to take each record (second field), say on row 2 `"TELMINORM CH 40/12.5MG TAB 10'S"` and make a fuzzy comparison with the rest of the records and find if there exists a similar record set.

An example would be
`TELMINORM CH 40/12.5MG TAB 10'S` is same as `TELMINORM CH 40/12.5MG CAP 10'S`. Tablet/Capsule is what is meant by TAB/CAP. In this case its a duplicate record.

So to eliminate this I used `distance` module and then if the difference of the string is less than 5, I am writing to a file in below format.

```
TELMINORM CH 40/12.5MG TAB 10'S - TELMINORM CH 80/12.5MG TAB 10'S, TELMINORM CH 40/12.5MG TAB 10'S, TELMINORM CH 40/12.5MG CAP 10'S
```

The logic i used is doing the trick but slow. It processes 150 records in 1 hour
which is very slow process.

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
rank = fuzz.ratio("str_1", "str_2")
```

Then I check if the `rank > 80` and proceed. This method seems to be faster than the distance module.